# Cassandra: Storing and retrieving large sized values (50MB to 100 MB)

Tags: cassandra

I want to store and retrieve values from Cassandra which ranges from 50MB to 100MB.

As per documentation, Cassandra works well when the column value size is less than 10MB. Refer [here](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations)

My table is as below. Is there a different approach to this ?

```
CREATE TABLE analysis (
    prod_id text,
    analyzed_time timestamp,
    analysis text,
    PRIMARY KEY (slno, analyzed_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (analyzed_time DESC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large values can be problematic, as the coordinator needs to buffer each row on heap before returning them to a client to answer a query. There's no way to stream the analysis_text value.

Internally Cassandra is also not optimized to handle such use case very well and you'll have to tweak a lot of settings to avoid problems such as described by shutty.

Answer (score 4):

As for my own experience, although in theory Cassandra can handle large blobs, in practise it may be really painful. As for one of my past projects, we stored protobuf blobs in C* ranged from 3kb to 100kb, but there were some (~0.001%) of them with size up to 150mb. This caused problems:

- Write timeouts. By default C* has 10s write timeout which is really not enough for large blobs.
- Read timeouts. The same issue with read timeout, read repair, hinted handoff timeouts and so on. You have to debug all these possible failures and raise all these timeouts. C* has to read the whole heavy row to RAM from disk which is slow.

I personally suggest not to use C* for large blobs as it's not very effective. There are alternatives:

- Distributed filesystems like HDFS. Store an URL of the file in C* and file contents in HDFS.
- DSE (Commercial C* distro) has it's own distributed FS called CFS on top of C* which can handle large files well.
- Rethink your schema in a way to have much lighter rows. But it really depends of your current task (and there's not enough information in original question about it)